# Automatically export password protected Access Table to .csv file using Java

Tags: java, csv, ms-access

**What it needs to do.**
1. Browse filesystem for DB.
2. Open password protected DB. (Program will hold the password)
3. Select table.
4. Export the table into a .csv file.
**What I have.**
Nothing, I am currently planning and designing. I am somewhat new to programming and have made similar programs just not connected to Access. 
**Plan so far.**
I plan on using [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) to connect with the database and am not sure what would be needed to convert the database into the .csv file. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Although I know java I am more of a designer and am not great with syntax. I prefer to stick with Java but if there is an easier way I'm open to anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason why I developped UCanAccess is to allow SQL query executions.
The direct usage of the jackcess library export utility (class com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.ExportUtil) seems to fullfil your simple requirement. It will allow you to export tables in csv with no more than three rows of code.

Comment: Thank you. Yesterday I was still diving into everything but after some reading and your comment I have the program mostly done now. I hope to implement some of the UCanAccess features as well.